# How to upscale the death house and still keep it fun?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, curse-of-strahd

Due to Reasons™, my intro level to my current run of Curse of Strahd for a new group didn't involve the Death House, I wrote my own intro-level this time.

I always had a lot of fun running it for other groups, though, so wanted to keep it in the game for a later stage. I've already written it in the world in a place that's pretty likely to be found by the players.

The issue is that I still want to keep it a *Death* House, which it clearly is at levels 1-3, but I expect the party to find it at the earliest by level 5, probably 6. While it still would not be a breeze, I ran a number of the encounters with likely upscales of their current party and it did not feel deadly at all. I could just up all DCs and make each monster group a bit larger, but I don't feel like that's particularly interesting.

Assume my Plan™ survives first contact with the players and they find the House. What is an interesting way to upscale the Death House to party level 5-6? The party will be either 4 or 5 characters, depending on who can make which session, and the group is paranoid enough about dying that they seem to insist on running at least 2 healers at all times.

Comment: To the close voters: how is this question more opinionated than e.g. https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/121283/40167 which attracted good answers? An ideal answer to my question would be from experience of running the death house for groups it isn't designed for (either more/less party members, higher levels, different design).

Comment: Please define fun. Question you linked defines exciting and memorable in somewhat objective way. This one does not, and people have a wide spectrum of things that are fun to them. Often what's fun for one person is totally unfun for another.

Comment: Are you only worried about upscaling combat encounters - or are you also worried about the exploratory aspect since by that level player characters will have access to more tools?

Comment: What kind of experience are you trying to create, and what do you mean by upscaling? I don't know what you want to achieve here.

Comment: Are you asking, what makes the Death House fun, and how do I recreate the experience at a higher level?

Comment: I suggest you find out if the party losing multiple level 5-6 characters would be what they consider "fun" because in my experience that's what happens in DH.